# RealmDB does not get populated

Tags: swift, realm

New to Realm... so hopefully a simple fix!

I have a data object of:

```
class GasFile : Object {
  @objc dynamic var gasFilename : String = ""
 // @objc dynamic var gasCategory : String? = ""
}
```

In my `ViewController` I have the following function:

```
func PopulateRealmWithFilenames() {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    var path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
    path += "/NBTFiles"
    //let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
    let items : [String] = try! fm.subpathsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

    for item in items {
        do {
            print("item for realm is: \(item)")
            try self.realm.write {
                let newGasFile = GasFile()
                newGasFile.gasFilename.append(item)
                print("newGasFile written ok")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error writing new item to Realm \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

This sets up the RealmDB ok, but never gets populated.
 The aim of the function is to save all the filenames (not paths) of the files stored in a folder called `NBTFiles`.
 I get the 'newGasfile written ok printed out' so it is getting into the loop.
datatype error ?
(I know I could just put it into an Array, but I want to use realm)

Comment: Did you even read [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#working-with-realm-objects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you want to add new object to realm without using adding function ?
you should use  `realm.add(object: newGasFile)`

try this

```
func PopulateRealmWithFilenames() {
let fm = FileManager.default
var path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
path += "/NBTFiles"
//let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
let items : [String] = try! fm.subpathsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

for item in items {


    do {
        print("item for realm is: \(item)")
        try self.realm.write {
            let newGasFile = GasFile()
            newGasFile.gasFilename.append(item)
            realm.add(object: newGasFile)
            print("newGasFile written ok")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error writing new item to Realm \(error)")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: OMG! How embarrassed! Thank you - can't believe I missed .add - I am an idiot! thank you guru!